# Теория по массивам

Tags: c++, массивы

Подкиньте пожалуйста хорошую теорию с примерами по массивам, хочу разобраться как они работать и где в теории сделан упор на алгоритмическую часть работы с массивами. Язык программирования С++.

Comment: Странный вопрос из серии: "какая хорошая штука, интересно, зачем она?". Вопрос задаётся обычно с другой стороны: мне надо решить такую-то задачу. К каким структурам данных она приводит?

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на хорошее руководство по С++, [тут рассмотренны типы данных в целом](http://valera.asf.ru/cpp/book/c03.html)